# Auto populate lookup field through plugin in C# plugin in Dynamic CRM

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm

I am trying to auto populate account lookup field in my form upon selection of contact lookup field but when i perform it shows entity does not contain the respective id but when i debug it shows the right account name can any one let me know where i am making mistake?

```cs
Entity task = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
EntityReference lookupValue = task.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_contact");

if (lookupValue != null)
{
    string targetEntityName = lookupValue.LogicalName;
    Guid targetEntityId = lookupValue.Id;
    QueryExpression query_contactparty = new QueryExpression("contact");
    query_contactparty.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
    query_contactparty.ColumnSet.AddColumns("contactid");
    query_contactparty.ColumnSet.AddColumns("fullname");
    query_contactparty.ColumnSet.AddColumns("parentcustomerid");
    query_contactparty.Criteria.AddCondition("contactid", ConditionOperator.Equal, targetEntityId);

    LinkEntity accountLink = new LinkEntity("contact", "account", "parentcustomerid", "accountid", JoinOperator.Inner);
    accountLink.Columns = new ColumnSet("name");
    query_contactparty.LinkEntities.Add(accountLink);

    EntityCollection contactparty = service.RetrieveMultiple(query_contactparty);

    foreach (var con in contactparty.Entities)
    {
        Guid accountid = con.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("contactid");
        string name = con.GetAttributeValue<string>("fullname");
        EntityReference parentAccount = con.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("parentcustomerid");

        if (parentAccount != null)
        {
            //throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Value found is:" + name + " and id is: " + accountid + " account :" + parentAccount.Name);

            task["new_account"] = new EntityReference("new_kaispe", parentAccount.Id)
            {
                Name = parentAccount.Name
            };
        }

        service.Update(task);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a plugin pipeline handling the `Update` message, an `EntityReference` value can be set in the pre validation stage. The `Entity` found in the "Target" property of the `InputParameters` collection only needs to be modified. Do not try to update it using `service.Update(task)`.

Just remove that line and register your plugin for the pre validation stage.

Comment: Thanks alot, problem solved because of your help

Comment: Glad I could help. Perhaps you can flag my post as an answer. Can be helpful for other visitors.