# Use pre or post stage in Dataverse plugin create and update pipelines?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

I created a post operation plugin to update a lookup field called Request on an Order entity whenever this Order record is created or updated. This plugin works fine, but could somebody tell me if it is a good idea to run this plugin on a post-operation or maybe I should try register this plugin on a pre-operation?

```cs
public class UpdateOrderPlugIN : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // Extract the tracing service for use in debugging sandboxed plug-ins.
        ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

        try
        {
            // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            // The InputParameters collection contains all the data passed in the message request.
            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity targetEntity)
            {
                if (targetEntity.Attributes.Contains("abs_requestid"))
                {
                    tracingService.Trace("Update");

                    UpdateReference(tracingService, service, targetEntity);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> e)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in the UpdateOrderPlugIN", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tracingService.Trace($"updateReference: {e.ToString()}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static void UpdateReference(ITracingService tracingService, IOrganizationService service, Entity orderEntity)
    {
        tracingService.Trace("UpdateReference");
        var entityUpdate = new Entity(orderEntity.LogicalName, orderEntity.Id);
        string requestId = orderEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("abs_requestid");// this is a text field for storing Request ID for example 001, 002...
        var requestRef = new EntityReference("abs_request", "abs_requestid", requestId);// this is to retrieve Request record based ont he requestId value from text field
        tracingService.Trace($"requestID: {requestId}");
        entityUpdate["abs_request"] = requestRef;// populate Request lookup
        tracingService.Trace("Updating record");
        service.Update(entityUpdate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dataverse plugin pipelines handling the create and update messages for entities you can modify the attributes of the target entity in the stages that occur before the `main` stage. These are the `pre validation` and `pre operation` stages.

There is one exception regarding attributes of the `EntityReference` type: these attributes can only be modified in the pre validation stage, but not in the pre operation stage.

I strongly recommend using these stages in favor of the post stage, because:

- it is super efficient (it requires no I/O)
- you do not potentially trigger subsequent plugins that need further consideration/handling

So, your code could look as simple as this:

```cs
public class UpdateOrderPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        var target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

        if (target.Contains("abs_requestid"))
        {
            string requestId = target.GetAttributeValue<string>("abs_requestid");

            target["abs_request"] = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestId)
                ? new EntityReference("abs_request", new Guid(requestId))
                : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note:

- No checks needed on the existance of the target entity. In the create and update pipelines it will always be available in the `InputParameters` collection.
- Error handling is not really needed here.

See also [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75360165/auto-populate-lookup-field-through-plugin-in-c-sharp-plugin-in-dynamic-crm/).

Comment: Thanks @Henk van Boeijen for your reply. I tried to register then plugin as pre-validation on Order entity, however every time I'm trying to create a new Order I'm getting exception: `code Upsert failed with an exception. Error: ReferencingEntity=abs_order has attribute abs_request value=Guid.Empty for relationship=abs_request_abs_order_Order...` I'm trying to populate the lookup to make this relationship, so why I'm getting this exception?

Comment: Could be you need to try this: `target["abs_request"] = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestId) ? new EntityReference("abs_request", new Guid(requestId.Trim()) : null`. Otherwise, explain what should be in attribute `abs_requestid` and how lookup `abs_request` is setup.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion `string requestId = target.GetAttributeValue<string>("abs_requestid");` this is just a text field on Order record storing requestid then with `target["abs_request"] = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestId)
                ? new EntityReference("abs_request", "abs_requestid", requestId.Trim())
                : null;` I'm just trying to populate lookup called abs_request and the EntityReference is just use to find Request record (abs_requestid - primary key on Request). I will debug this more, however the error I'm receiving is  a litter bit confusing

Comment: I guess you are using the wrong contructor of `EntityReference`. Just use `new EntityReference("<entitylogicalname>", <Guid>)`. I modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

General rule of thumb for me is, if the user is updating something that would result in this value being updated it should happen in the same transaction (per operation).  Except, where that resulting update requires any potential long requests, sending an email, retrieving a result from an external service call or a large internal CRM transaction (creating several child records based on the update)

If you know the value your updating in the current context, there shouldn't be additional service.updates, roll it all into the current transaction.  For example if the user enters a quantity and you're calculating the correct sub total, that sub total should be updated as a pre operation vs post operation.

The benefit is that you are not adding additional transactions, which cause subsequent plugins/automation to fire again (assuming those plugins would fire on the initial create / update anyway). You also avoid increasing the depth of subsequent transactions that occur in the pipeline.

In your example, it depends on how you want to handle the Request ID being invalid.  I'd recommend against your current code, as you're assuming the user is entering the a valid guid for the request table.  This would give you a hard exception.  I'd suggest that you query the request table for the record, if it exists, bind it, else do some error handling.

With that in mind, I'd make this a per operation, assuming you want to stop the user from entering an invalid request ID, as pre operation will always be sync, and thus any failure, that you don't handle, will result in an exception and the transaction would roll back.

Here is a nice post with some details: https://temmyraharjo.wordpress.com/2018/08/17/pre-operation-vs-post-operation-plugin-customization/