# Dataverse Date and Time column with custom date format

Tags: dynamics-crm, dataverse

I have to show a Dataverse Table in Dynamics 365 with a Date and Time column with a custom date format: weekday,day, month, year, ours, minutes.

I can't find the way to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this requirement cannot be achieved by adding a calculated field. Instead add a string field. Then create a plugin with steps registered for the pre operation create and pre operation update stages (synchronous). The update stage should only be triggered when the original `DateTime` attribute is modified. The plugin sets the value of the string field using common .NET DateTime formatting.

See also [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75766474/use-pre-or-post-stage-in-dataverse-plugin-create-and-update-pipelines).

Comment: Thank you! I have only one problem... If I insert a date in a new record the extended date is correct but if I update a record without modify the date the date field results to be 0001-01-01 00:00. Any ideas?

Comment: Filter your plugin step so it only fires when the date record is actually modified. When this is not a vailable solution, add a pre image to the step holding the existing attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PCF Control to implement this requirement.

I am not aware if a control inside [PCF Gallery](https://pcf.gallery/) already show this format, however you can check existing controls and eventually extend them.